# CBC analysis using choicemodelr - interpretation of the output attribute values

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis, choice-modeling

I finished a choice-based conjoint (CBC) survey. Now i am evaluating my results with the R-Package "ChoiceModelR". With this i get Beta Values, with which i can, for example, compute attribute importances. One of my attributes is price.
I now want to see how the other attributes relate to the price attribute, meaning that if i visualize the results on a coordinate axis, i have price on the x-axis and the choice likelihood or utility on the y-axis. i want to know, how do the the levels of the other attributes change if i e.g. increase the price. As an example, one attribute is price (e.g. 200, 300 and 400 Dollars), another one is brand (e.g. Samsung and LG). Now i could find out that if i increase the price from 300 to 400 Dollars, the brand becomes more important (concerning choice likelihood or utility) than at 200 Dollars.

Is that possible, and if yes, how can i implement/compute it in R and ChoiceModelR?

Thanks!

Comment: You should include an interaction between price and brand in your choice model.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the covariance matrix and correlation matrix for the attributes price and brand amongst others. Suppose the output of ChoiceModelR is hb.post. To find the covariance matrix and correlation matrix:

```
# find the covariance matrix and correlation matrix from the 700th draw
covariance <-crossprod(hb.post$compdraw[[700]]$rooti)
correlation <- cov2cor(covariance)
```

The script is taken from p. 393 of

Chapman, C. and Feit, E. M. (2015). R for Marketing Research and Analytics. Switzerland: Springer International Publishing AG.